# Custom client side validation not picking the regex

Tags: c#, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

## Goal

Create Custom client side validation using `AttributeAdapterBase` and `IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider`.

## Problem

I have built a form input element using tag helper.
This form/ViewComponent loads when any user selects a radio button.

Also, I have built custom client side validation in C#
using `AttributeAdapterBase<SomeIdAttribute>`.

I have a `ViewComponent` with the following field decorated as below:

```
[SomeId(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+[.]+[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"]
public string SomeId{ get; set; }
```

Another field with `CustomValidation` and regex `[TenantId("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{36}$")]` works fine.

The problem occurs in the code below in method `AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)`:

```
MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-regex-pattern", Attribute.RegexPattern);
```

The regex mentioned above isn't parsed successfully and regex-pattern stays as `null` while rendering the HTML.

For parsing, I have used the line below:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#someformID'));
```

If I change the regex to some simple format, it works. But this particular regex is not getting assigned.

Is it missing some escape sequence somewhere?

If we use built in `RegularExpression` , still the issue is the same.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I improved the English and source code formatting of your post. Please take a look (click the `edit` link to see what's the source of this post) and try to format your code next time like what I did. Thanks!